# nodejs express api performance issue

Tags: node.js, performance, express, router

I have Api made with express and some database things.

- My router is dynamically created from separated files and then imported and used in express

On first run, with a first request to api (doesn't matter what endpoint), run is always long, can get to 10 seconds. I am guessing it's because it's generating router on that firs run ? 
Is there any way to load it fully right away ?

After couple of other requests to api, it's much faster. around 100-200ms. 
But if I leave it unused and use it again after minuet or two, it's slow again.
I was thinking it's database queries, but I have some really simple and fast ones. Using knex I can time them out and it seems to be fast enough. 
Also I don't produce console logs as I know that can slow it down too.

Also, I am actually using node http server and then using express inside it. 
Is it all because of that structure ? or problem could be somewhere else ?

my main server.js

```js
import app from './createExpressApp'

const server = require('http').createServer()
server.on('request', app)

...
```

my createExpressApp.js

```js
import router from './app/routes/'

...

app.use('/api/v1',router)
.set('etag', false) //disable caching
.use((req, res, next) => {
    // disable caching
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private')
    next()
  })

...
```

and my router index.js

```js
import { sync } from 'glob'
import { Router } from 'express'


var router = sync('**/*.js', { cwd: `${__dirname}/` })
  .map((filename) => require(`./${filename}`).default)
  .filter((router) => Object.getPrototypeOf(router) === Router)
  .reduce(
    (rootRouter, router) =>
      rootRouter.use(router),
    Router({ mergeParams: true })
  )
export default router
```

Comment: Is `sync` strictly necessary? Seems a heavy process

Comment: The issue is not with the code shown, but elsewhere. Probably with the downstream API call(s).

Comment: @Rashomon I wanted to make router "smart" so I can just create files with routers and that will do the rest. but I might go to classic option and import each file manually myself.

Comment: @rustyx do you know any way to try to investigate that ? or somehow measure , where is that "delay" in the code ? or I would just have to make global timer and print it in console in different points ?

Comment: It drives me insane, can someone explain, why that can happen? I replaced my router with  "normal" router. but it's still the same. When running first time it comes to 2 seconds, same endpoint straight after takes 400ms, and if I keep requesting it's about the same. but after minute it's 2 seconds again.